# Convert Date from Mail message into dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Tags: java

I'm using a Java mail client to read my emails. The Date field contained in the message reads as:

```
Sat Dec 20 12:25:54 CET 2014
```

I wonder if there is a safe way to convert it in Java to a language independent format such as:

```
dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat To parse String representing `Sat Dec 20 12:25:54 CET 2014` E.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

If you want date to be converted into String `dd/MM/YYYY HH:MM` then specify this format to [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
String s = sdf2.format(new Date());
```